# JQuery click target

Tags: jquery, click, slick.js

I've implemented this awesome codepen into my site: 
https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz

```
$('.display-image')
.on('change', function(){
  $(this).children('img').css({'transform': 'scale('+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +')'});
})
.on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).children('img').css({'transform': 'scale('+ $(this).attr('data-scale') +')'});
})
.on('mouseout', function(){
  $(this).children('img').css({'transform': 'scale(1)','transition': 'transform .3s ease-out'});
})
.on('mousemove', function(e){
  $(this).children('img').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
})
```

Problem is I am targeting a slick slider object:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

And when the slick is filtered the target object, '.display-image', no longer registers these click events. How do I go about retargeting this object?

Answer (score 0):

Consider giving the slider an ID and then referencing it as $('#id') instead of by style class (which is how jquery is looking up the dot-display-image).

Comment: The images in the slider are generated in a for loop; so I would need to have unique ID's. Then the jquery would need to look at the ID of each or with wildcard. Does that make it any different?

Comment: A wildcard should work.
Ex `$('img[name^="startsWithSomething"]')`

Comment: Thanks Iceman - but this doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the solution. In order for the code to see any change in the event listener, instead of having:

```
$('.display-image').on('click', function() {*code here*});
```

I changed it to

```
$(document).on('click', '.display-image', function() {*code here*});
```